# I cannot reopen eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have an existing project in eclipse, until Thursday this project was working, but Friday I have tried to update the code, but I had a problem with smartgit, then I have tried to take the files directly from a cloud and reapply manually at eclipse, I had some problems and I have tried to delete the .project in hope to eclipse will recreate this, after I have tried to reapply the original version of my devroot, but nothing, when I see eclipse the project is open like this [image]

thank you for your help, I need it

Comment: You have to restore the `.project` file e. g. by creating a project of the same type to copy the `.project` file from it and adapting the project name in the copied file. Alternatively, use _File > Open Projects from File System..._.

Comment: 1 ) Take the backup and Continue. 2 )If it is the maven project you can export the project in Specified Folder.When ever it necessary in your code development process you can import same maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source code is still intact, just create a new project and copy your source code over. Another way is to copy it again from the cloud and import the project to eclipse.

Comment: I have tried to reapply old code and to reuse old devroot, but the result on eclipse was the same

Answer (score 1):

is it a **maven** project? or **java**? if **maven** just do a

**mvn eclipse:eclipse** then 
this will regenrate .project and .classpath files

and then do a maven build

**mvn clean install -DskipTests**
rebuild your project by deleting the target folder and adding the required dependencies and you can try again in  eclipse.

*Last, if you have both the files for your project and still it is not opening then you need to delete .metadata folder of your eclipse and re import the projects.*

Comment: No, isn't a maven project, however I did it, thank you for your reply